# A class within a class, should this be fixed or is it intentional?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inner-classes, python-3.5

Today I was experimenting and / or messing around with Python 3.5.

I happened to *"accidentally"* write this:

```
class Apple(object):
    class green(object):
        def eat():
            print("You just ate a green apple...")

    class red(object):
        def eat():
            print("You just ate a red apple...")
```

Meaning I can now do:

```
Apple.red.eat() # would print: "You just are a red apple..."
Apple.green.eat() # would print: "You just are a green apple..."
```

Which led me to ask is this how functions such as `os.path.exists()` are created or are they created using another *"method"*?
Should this be fixed, or was it intentional?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that `import os` gets all content from `os.py`... so `path` must be a `class` inside the `os.py` file and `exists()` must be a  `function` inside `path` class.

Comment: `os.path` is a **submodule**, `os` is a **package**.

Comment: if `os.path` was a class then you could make instances of `os.path` which doesn't make any sense, same issue with your code.  Doing `x = Apple.red() ; x.eat()` raises an error because `eat` is not a valid method (missing the `self` argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes within classes work just fine in python -- However, python's primary mechanism for handling namespaces is *modules* and *packages*, not classes.  I've not found a whole lot of use for classes within classes (though there probably are *some* valid use-cases).

To set up something like `os.path.exists`, I would direct you to the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/os.py#l46) except that `os.path` does some pretty sketchy things to set up its namespace (modifying `sys.modules`) and avoids using packages.  You're better off creating a package unless you need to conditionally import different things under the same name...

In this case, to set up a package, you might use a directory structure something like <sup>1</sup>:

```
apples
  +--  __init__.py  (empty)
  |
  +--  base.py  (holds BaseApple class)
  |
  +--  green.py (holds GreenApple which inherits from BaseApple)
  |
  +--  red.py  (holds RedApple which inherits from BaseApple)
```

Then, assuming your PYTHONPATH can find everything correctly, you'd do:

```
from apples.green import GreenApple
from apples.red import RedApple
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Obviously, this is just one of *many* ways you can set it up.  Without having a real example of what you're doing it's hard to give any concrete advice</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your time & help, I appreciate it, +1.